# Unexpected line break even though CR and LF not present in text file

Tags: text, line-breaks

I have this text file which has ASCII characters as well as the bytes 1C and 1D appended at the end. When I open this file in Windows notepad or atom it has line breaks, which are not intended or expected, even though there are no CR or LF characters.

Any explanations and solutions such that the bytes are in the file but do not show up as line breaks?

[file.txt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=30423160396112081937)

[hexdump](http://pastebin.com/MCEh2QMu)

Thanks!

Comment: Switch off word wrap in your text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like it is the length of the file rather than the group/file separators (HEX 1C/1D).  Shorter combinations of them lead to fewer displayed 'blank lines'.  They also aren't affected by word wrapping like printable characters.  Notepad++ handles them much better